# Solspace User (edit) allow member to change their own group?

Tags: solspace, solspace-user, member-management, solspace-facebookconnect

I'm using Solspace User and `{exp:user:edit}`.

I notice there is a form field `<input type="text" name="group_id" value="{group_id}" />`  but docs say its only visible to SA's.

Is there any way to make this visible to the logged in user so they have permission to change their own member group?

In `{exp:user:register}` new users have the option of picking their member group from your list of "allowed groups" yet they don't have the ability to edit that group later if they pick the wrong group.

This becomes more important when you also implement **Solspace Facebook Connect**, which allows passive registrations but all passive registrations must go to the same member group. Since passive registrations don't get the choice of choosing their member group on sign up, I need a way for them to edit the member group later.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you had a look at the `allowed_groups=""` parameter for `{exp:user:edit}`: http://www.solspace.com/docs/user/edit/#allowed_groups. Also, have you personally tried an `{exp:user:edit}` form with `allowed_groups=""` and a `group_id` field and it failed? Something tells me the docs just need to be tweaked.

Comment: No actually I haven't tried it. I just assumed from the way the docs are worded that it's not possible unless you are admin. I will have a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that this does work if you include all possible allowed groups in the `allowed_groups` parameter and then use a form field with name `group_id` and value as the chosen group ID. Solspace please update your docs to eliminate where it says the group_id form field is available to Super Admins only.